# Create an object with only some attributes from another object in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, shorthand

With the new [ES6 syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), it's easy to only select some keys of an object and assign their values to variables with the same name. It goes like

```
let foo = {a: 2, b: 1, c:6};
{a, b} = foo;
```

which is equivalent to

```
let a = foo.a, b = foo.b;
```

It's also [easier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to create objects from variables, like

```
let bar = {a, b}
```

which is equivalent to

```
x = {a: a, b: b}
```

Now is there a shorthand to get `bar` from `foo` directly? (with `bar = {a: foo.a, b: foo.b}`)

Comment: How is `foo` and `bar` related?

Comment: thanks, I updated the question